# How can I get a HTML element in Xcode?

Tags: html, iphone, xcode, internet-radio

I have a problem which I can't resolve.

Here it is:
I am trying to make a radio app for iPhone. I am using an online stream, so I want to display the current song in a label.
How to do that?
Here is the list with the songs for the day and the current song: http://live.radioeuphoria.bg:41232/played.html?sid=1.

So, how to get the HTML element that says which is the current song?
How to do that in Xcode?

Comment: Can't you just the stream to retrieve the currently playing song? With  [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/DigitalDJ/AudioStreamer) you can just read the stream meta data and get the current song.

Comment: for parsing html you can use https://github.com/topfunky/hpple

Comment: I am afraid it's too complicated for me at my current level. I don't get what all the code is doing. ;( If anybody can help me with some example.. Would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSURLConnection` to get the html as a string. Then use `NSXMLParser` to get the tags and values.

`NSURLConnection`: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

`NSXMLParser`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I am not so good at English and I can't understand everything. Can you please give me some example based on the link I gave in my first post? The current title song is in a **table -> tr -> the second td element**. How to get this element, because it hasn't any id or class? Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, but this is a bunch of code, please start to get the response from requesting the url first. When you have that, start parsing.